# What is the time complexity recursive function to find Max value of array?

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode

I have a pseudocode :

```
//1 is the starting index here
function maximum_element(array[1 to N])
    if N=1 do
        return array[1]
    elseif array[1] > maximum_element(array[2 to N])
        return array[1]
    else
        return maximum_element(array[2 to N])
```

I have found the best case : Where N = 1 -> No recursion so O(1);
But for the worst case, where element are perfectly ascending in order, what is the time complexity? It is iterated N-1, N-2, N-3 ... times so the time complexity should be O(n!)? or the upper bound can be tightened? Please explain how I could get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **O(n)**. Because this is essentially a for-loop that iterates over every element once.

If you think about it. Finding the maximum in an unordered list should always be O(n) because you have to visit each element once. O(n!) would be very bad for a max algorithm.